# i want to access the transaction from web panel and directly through developer menu(

Tags: genexus

I want to access my transaction from web panel(send  variables to the transaction ) and I want to access this from the developer menu screen (without variables)

Comment: Provide some code example?

Answer (score 0):

How are you?.

Thats is very simple Try with some like this

WebPanel
put in it ONLY a GRID with a several attributes from such TRANSACTION, change the property main=true and Choice option RUN WITH THIS ONLY.

Form more details, you can write to my gmail: @gxsoft 
Kind regards,
gab